# Setting Up Remote Access On mySQL Server Client Throwing Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

This is my first time trying to set up an SQL server. I used the installation client on mySQL and that all went fine, I can look at tables and edit them, but I want to be able to do it from the mySQL client on my Mac (The server is hosted on server running Windows Server 2008 r2).

I've tried using every variation of

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

going but it just throws the error 1064 (42000) near IDENTIFIED BY 'password';.

I've literally copied at least 10 variations of it and it says the same thing every time.

Is it something stupidly simple or have I not done it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

remove the **IDENTIFIED BY 'password'** then grant password later with **ALTER**